# Google Maps InfoWindow Not Populating After Map Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a modal that has 3 links (think tabs) using a hide/show div switch. 1st link is an image. 2nd link is a google map. 3rd link is a 2nd google map. Each are opening fine in the modal. The problem is that initially, the 2nd and 3rd link's map's info windows are very small with only the close button. If I click the 2nd or 3rd link again, the info window finally populates.

It feels like they aren't being redrawn after the resize code, but I'm confused on how to redraw them to fix the problem.

Code I'm using for the maps (other map is the same, but different location):

```
<script>
    var myCenterHelena=new google.maps.LatLng(46.596994, -112.037184);
    var mapHelena;
    function initializeHelena() {
        var mapOptionsHelena = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myCenterHelena,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        mapHelena = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('modalGoogleMapHelena'),
            mapOptionsHelena
        );
        var contentStringHelena = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"></div>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent" style="line-height:16px; font-size:14px; padding:10px; text-align:center;">'+
        '<p>ikuw solutions, inc<br>' +
        '863 great northern blvd, ste 103<br>' +
        'helena, mt 59601<br><br>'+
        '<a href="http://www.getikuw.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FF8000;">'+
        'www.getikuw.com</a><br>'+
        '844-get-ikuw</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        var infowindowHelena = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentStringHelena
        });

        var markerHelena = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenterHelena,
            animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            map: mapHelena,
            //title: 'ikuw Solutions, Inc'
        });
        infowindowHelena.open(mapHelena,markerHelena);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeHelena);
    </script>
    <!--resize map after tab load-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href=#subDivTab3]').on('click', function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                //reset map
                google.maps.event.trigger(mapHelena, 'resize');
                // also redefine center
                mapHelena.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(46.596994, -112.037184));
            }, 75);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It feels like this line `infowindowHelena.open(mapHelena,markerHelena);` should be after the resize code, but it isn't working :/

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"?  Any javascript errors in the console?  Probably needs to be global to use it in the setTimeout function.

Comment: No errors. "Not working" means the contentString isn't being populated in the InfoWindow. Doesn't work in the above code, nor does it work if I put "infowindowHelena.open(mapHelena,markerHelena);" after the resize code. My gut says that line should appear after the resize code...but I'm sort of new at this, so not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opening the infowindow in the setTimeout works works for me (if I make the infowindow and the marker global):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href=#modalGoogleMapHelena]').on('click', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //reset map
            google.maps.event.trigger(mapHelena, 'resize');
            // also redefine center
            mapHelena.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(46.596994, -112.037184));
            infowindowHelena.open(mapHelena, markerHelena);
        }, 75);
    });
});
```

proof of concept fiddles:

- [not working - your original code](http://jsfiddle.net/tpxtbxvp/)
- [working - with above described change](http://jsfiddle.net/tpxtbxvp/1/)

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you so much. Robert's help worked as well, but not as I originally asked. Much thanks to you both :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script>
    var myCenterHelena=new google.maps.LatLng(46.596994, -112.037184);
    var mapHelena;
    var infowindowHelena = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function initializeHelena() {
        var mapOptionsHelena = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myCenterHelena,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        mapHelena = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('modalGoogleMapHelena'),
            mapOptionsHelena
        );

        var markerHelena = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenterHelena,
            animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            map: mapHelena,
            //title: 'ikuw Solutions, Inc'
        });

        var contentStringHelena = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"></div>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent" style="line-height:16px; font-size:14px; padding:10px; text-align:center;">'+
        '<p>ikuw solutions, inc<br>' +
        '863 great northern blvd, ste 103<br>' +
        'helena, mt 59601<br><br>'+
        '<a href="http://www.getikuw.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FF8000;">'+
        'www.getikuw.com</a><br>'+
        '844-get-ikuw</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(markerHelena,'click', (function(markerHelena,contentStringHelena,infowindowHelena){ 
           return function() {
              infowindowHelena.setContent(contentStringHelena);
              infowindowHelena.open(mapHelena, markerHelena);
           };
        })(markerHelena,contentStringHelena,infowindowHelena));
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeHelena);
    </script>
    <!--resize map after tab load-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href=#subDivTab3]').on('click', function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                //reset map
                google.maps.event.trigger(mapHelena, 'resize');
                // also redefine center
                mapHelena.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(46.596994, -112.037184));
            }, 75);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great! I took your code snippet and applied it to both maps and they both work on reveal. However, is there a way to make it so you don't have to click on the marker to get the infowindow to appear? So it automatically shows? Or was that the only way to get this to work? BTW, that bouncing marker is annoying as hell, LOL. I'm going to take that off.